# jquery validation allow to enter code between user1 to user100

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

This is my the example where user can enter the code between 1 to 100 only otherwise return false.

```js
var regexCode = /var regexEmail = /^0*(?:[1-9][0-9]?|100)$/;

 
 $(document).on('change','#code',function(){
    if (!regexCode.test($("input#code").val())) {
      alert("Please enter valid code");
      $("input#code").focus();
      return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="code" id="code" placeholder="code" required>
```

Now it accepting digits between 1 to 100 but I need it to accept the code e.g between

`user1` to `user100` only otherwise return false.

Comment: Did you try replacing `var regexCode = /var regexEmail = /^0*(?:[1-9][0-9]?|100)$/;` with `var regexCode = /^0*(?:[1-9][0-9]?|100)$/;` becasue first line makes and error

Comment: you want it accepts 1 to 100 and user1 to user100 or only user1 to user100?

Comment: @Frenchy It should accept, between user1 to user100 rather than 1 to 100.

Comment: it accepts too user01 or user001?

Comment: @Frenchy No sir, only should accept between user1 to user100 so it can be e.g user1, user2 upto user100. any one from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lot of solution with : regexp

```js
var regexCode = /^user(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,1}|100)$/;

 
 $(document).on('change','#code',function(){
    var result = $("input#code").val();
    if (!regexCode.test($("input#code").val())) {
      alert("Please enter valid code");
      $("input#code").focus();
      return false;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="code" id="code" placeholder="code" required>
```

Comment: Its allowing user01 not user1 only. it should allow only code between user1 between user100 if anyone entered user01 so should return false or eliminate first zero from it.

Comment: with more explanations its ok

Comment: Sir, it is going across user100 as well if we enter user101 or user111 it is accepting them to. It can be modify to accept under user100 only if it is goes beyond user100 like user101 or user111 so should return false as well. tnx.

Comment: If i want to increase my capacity upto 300 like code should accept between user1 to user 300 so. i have changed regex to this var regexCode = /^user(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,1}|300)$/; but didn't worked for me. can you make it little changes on it plz.

Comment: try var regexCode = /^user(?:[1-9][0-9]{0,1}|[1-2][0-9][0-9]|300)$/;

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex `/^[1-9][0-9]$|^100$/` explain:

`^[1-9][0-9]?` should mens starts digit with two or one (first doesn't accept 0 )range number - `0 --> 99`

`|` or operator

`^100$` start and end only with the number `100`

also think to remove last added number from value using :

```
value = value.substring(0, value.length - 1);
$(this).val(value);
```

Belw in snippt I've used on `Input` event to check for every keyboard input

```js
var regexCode = /^[1-9][0-9]?$|^100$/;

 
 $(document).on('input','#code',function(e){
    let value = $(this).val();
    
    
    if (!regexCode.test($(this).val())) {
      alert("Please enter valid code");
      value = value.substring(0, value.length - 1);
      $(this).val(value)
      $("input#code").focus();
      return false;
    } else {
      $("#output").html("user"+value)
    }
    
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="code" id="code" placeholder="code" required> rang betwwen 0-100
<br><br>
user id = <span id="output"></span>
```

Comment: Yes. but can you modify it to accept the code between user1 to user100 if anyone entered user01 so eliminate first zero and if we entered user101 than mentioned range should also return false. tnx

Comment: @mdserver , yep , you're right , fixed now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML Pattern for this purpose.

```
<input type="text" name="code" id="code" placeholder="code" pattern="user[0-9]{1,2}" required />
```

Comment: its accepting user999 as well, the rule is first zero should be remove and also accept the code between user1 to user100 only.